# Error : Program received Signal : "SIGABRT" , How to Sovle this error in XCode 4.0.2?

Tags: ios, ios4

I am new in iPhone technology, i am making one sample iPhone application in XCode 4.0.2 and   getting error while i am executing my iPhone. I simply wants to show the text field value in a lable on Button Click event. but the application is showing error on this line

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, nil);   
  // Error Pointing on Above line  as Thread 1 : Program received Signal : "SIGABRT"

    [pool release];
    return retVal;
}
```

as  . I tried but error is not going ... Can Anyone help me !!!!

This is my code for : helloworldViewController.m

```
#import "helloworldViewController.h"

@implementation helloworldViewController

@synthesize Text;
@synthesize Label;
@synthesize goButton;


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

-(IBAction)Go: (id) sender
{
    NSString *str = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Hello, %@", Text.text];
    //NSLog(@"%@",str);
    //NSLog(@"Hey, M working on button click event !!! Finish");
    [Text resignFirstResponder ];

    //This Code is For Displaying the Enterred Textfield value into Label.
    [Label setText:str];  
}

#pragma mark - View lifecycle

// Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];   
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return YES;
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

And Below one is for :  helloworldViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface helloworldViewController : UIViewController {

}
@property(nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UITextField *Text;
@property(nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UILabel *Label;
@property(nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UIButton *goButton;

-(IBAction)Go: (id) sender;

@end
```

### In Console Window i am getting Below one error :

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<UICustomObject 0x4b31e00> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key navigationController.'
```

Regards,

Tauseef Khan

Answer (score 0):

Your code is all ok. Instead of some Naming conventions ;) I recommend this doc http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/Articles/NamingBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001281-BBCHBFAH

I think that you have set up a Connection in Interface Builder to the View Controller wich send this Message at wich the ViewController has no method for.

Comment: I solved it brother...Thanks for giving link...It is one of the Best Link for learning Cocos2d....Once again thanks.


Regards,
Tauseef Khan